# Share long proofs in beamer to many frames

Tags: beamer, framed, proof-package

Hi everyone please I am writing a proof in beamer with
\begin{proof} \end{proof}
but the proof is too long so I can't have it in one frame, I wanted to share the proof to many frames but it didn't work.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you break up the proof material across several `frame`s. Use `\frametitle` to inform your audience that what they're being shown is a something that streches across several frames. E.g.,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%% load packages, define special macros, etc.
\begin{document}
% material that precedes the proof

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Proof of \dots}
\dots
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Proof of \dots, continued}
\dots
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Proof of \dots, continued}
\dots
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Proof of \dots\ (final page)}
\dots
\end{frame}

% material that follows the proof
\end{document}
```